# How to grant a user 'log on as a service' rights programmatically

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-services

I created a new user using the Windows 7 command line:

```
net user password /add
```

I want to use this user to start a newly-created service. However, it's not possible due to lack of "log on as a service" rights.

Is there a way to grant permissions to this user programmatically or by using the command line?

Comment: If you took out "using command line", and left only "programmatically using Windows API", your question would be on-topic here.  Questions asking for command-line tools provided with Windows are off-topic though.  You'd still need to fix your tags and explain what you're already tried, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically, you would use the [`LsaAddAccountRight` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721786.aspx) to add the `SE_SERVICE_LOGON_NAME` right.

MSDN has [a partial example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721863.aspx)